# ASPX SelectParameters From aspx.vb Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, ado.net

I am using ASP Classic 2.0 so I know some of this code is a bit outdated but it is what I inherited. I am trying to use a variable from my backing aspx.vb page in the select query.

I have the following query (truncated)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
            ConnectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=dataSQL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=$$$$"
            ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"

            SelectCommand="SELECT ClID, Client_Name
            FROM [tblClient]
            WHERE (tblClient.ClID = @ClID )"
            <SelectParameters>
              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="ClID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
              Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to replace the ControlParameter with a variable from the aspx.vb that backs this aspx page.

I know I have access to the variable because `<%=ClID%>` produces the correct ID but adding something `.Add("ClID", DbType.Guid, clID)` does not work.

I am guessing there is an easy way to do this.

If it needs to be a control I think I can bind ClID to the a form control but I cannot figure out the correct syntax for that.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: When you see ASP Classic, it refers to pre-.Net vbscript Active Server Pages, not asp.net web forms.

Answer (score 0):

First, for the `<%=CLID%>` remark remember that `<%=` is just shorthand for `Response.Write()`, meaning the result is only written into the final html rendered to the browser. *It does not and never will insert values into aspx markup.*

The `.Add()` code, however, is on the right track, but we still need to make two adjustments.

First, in the aspx markup use an `<asp:Parameter` instead of `<asp:ControlParameter`.

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
            ConnectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=dataSQL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=$$$$"
            ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"

            SelectCommand="SELECT ClID, Client_Name
            FROM [tblClient]
            WHERE tblClient.ClID = @ClID"
            <SelectParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="ClID" DbType="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then, in the aspx.vb code-behind instead of `.Add()` you must remember the parameter *already exists*. If you try to add it again you'll get an exception. Instead, you need to set the `Value` for the existing parameter in your code-behind:

```vb
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters["ClID"].Value = ClID
```

It's been a loooong time since I've used code like this, so you may also need to call `.DataBind()`

Comment: thank you.  I tried  `<SelectParameters>
 <asp:Parameter SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters["ClID"].Value = "ClID"
 />
  </SelectParameters>`  and I get this error "Literal content ('<asp:Parameter SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters["ClID"].Value = "ClID" />') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection'.".  In Visual Studio I see "Validation (ASP.Net): The attribute name must be followed by equal (=) sign and a value."  This is under SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand.Parameters.  I added the quotes to = "ClID" but I am not sure what else would have quotes.

Comment: @skessler-Grupp Setting the value must be done from the code behind. You cannot do it in markup if you want it to depend on a variable name. Especially for `<%=CLID%>`, remember that `<%=` is just shorthand for `Response.Write()`, meaning the result is only written into the final html rendered to the browser. _It doesn't not and never will insert values into aspx markup._

Comment: Hmm... promoting that last part into the answer.

Comment: I appreciate your patience with me.  I am new to ASP/VB.  The code block I included in the question with the ASP: tags is in the aspx page markup.  I think there is  away I can push this to the aspx.vb code I have but right now the query is in tags in the markup.  I am sorry but I am not sure what you are pointing me at in this context comment a couple hours ago. Thank you very much for your help! A little bit of honesty I did some VB in collage 18 years ago, but I do not remember any of it :)

Comment: Keep the aspx markup mostly as it was in the question. The only difference is converting to an `asp:Parameter` instead of `asp:ControlParameter`. The other part of the answer goes in the aspx.vb code-behind. Updated the answer to help.

Comment: Joel, I appreciate your help. What function does the code in the aspx.vb go into. Thanks!

Comment: That depends on what you are doing with this and how the variable is used.

Comment: I am just lost because I can get to my ClId variable if do something like ` Response.Write(@ClID)` but I cannot directly reference it in the aspx.vb file. The variable comes from my aspx.vb file but I am not sure what I would need to do to reference it in the aspx.vb file as a parameter for the query on the apsx page. Thanks!